# Should I be using something else besides GoalSeek?

Tags: vba, excel

Background, so I need to optimize daily sales without exceeding daily capacity and without going over a End of the period(EOP) total capacity. So I thought the code was working fine then I realized all it's doing is taking daily capacity to 0 until my EOP capacity reaches my target. So it's basically all or nothing so sometimes my target doesn't get hit. i.e your off by 150 units from EOP target but your daily capacity is all 200+ so it never hits the target I want. (I should mention sales could be negative)

So is goal seek what I really want? Can I set Goal to be a range(eg -10 to 10) maybe?

```
Sub cashPark()


    Set enddate = Sheets("Cash").Range("E4")
    Set Window = Sheets("Cash").Range("D8")
    Set TargetWindow = Sheets("Cash").Range("D14")
    Set datecount = Sheets("Cash").Range("E4")
    Set cashParkVol = Sheets("Inventory").Range("BW1")
    Set Repeate = Sheets("Cash").Range("E5")

    cashParkVol.Offset(datecount, -2).GoalSeek _
     Goal:=0 And Window.Value = TargetWindow, _
     ChangingCell:=cashParkVol.Offset(datecount, 0)


    Let x = 0
    Do While x < Repeate
    cashParkVol.Offset(datecount + x, -2).GoalSeek _
        Goal:=0 And Window.Value = TargetWindow, _
        ChangingCell:=cashParkVol.Offset(datecount + x, 0)
    x = x + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Sorry for the constant questions but I'm just getting more involved with VBA and I'm loving it so I'm trying to automate everything I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solver is the tool of choice for optimizing in Excel and it can be run from VBA. If you are not familiar with the tool, you should probably first figure out how to use it in Excel for your problem and then figure out how to automate it with VBA. [Frontline System](http://www.solver.com/) wrote and maintains the Solver Add-in and their website has some tutorials and examples. There are a number of books (e.g. "Spreadsheet Modeling and Decision Analysis" by Cliff Ragsdale) about using the solver. Ragsdale's book has examples involving clash-flow problems. If you really want to become a power-user with scripting the Solver with VBA, I recommend the book "VBA for Modelers" by S. Christian Albright since it is the only book that I know of that really focuses on solutions built around the Solver.

Comment: Thanks John, that's some great advice.  you're not the first person that recommended i learn Solver.  but $280 for a book it's a little steep for me this year.  any other good suggestions for learning solver from the ground up?